# use object property to add property on other object in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have an object that has a property required that i want to extend from another type, eg:

```
interface FabricObjectWithId extends fabric.Object {
 id: string
}
```

interface INeedPropsOfThisObj has no id, so on MyObj interface, i want to add id property but i got error. help?

this is my use case:

```
private getObjectOnCanvasById = (id: string) =>
    this.handler.canvas
      .getObjects()
      .find((obj:  FabricObjectWithId)  => obj.id === id);
```

the error message:

```
 Types of parameters 'obj' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'FabricObjectWithId'.
```

Comment: What does `getObjects()` return? It seems like it has the wrong return type.